# How to make my "add in" pop up automatically when my outlook is launched

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have created an Outlook Add-in using XML, HTML, css and JS in visual studio. I've to manually go to the outlook plugins or (more apps)  to open it. how to make my add-in automatically open when Outlook is launched?

Answer (score 0):

(1) There is no way currrently to launch an addin automatically after Outlook is launched.

(2) Addins always run in the context of email message or calendar invite. So, mere "Outlook Launch" does not tell us if there is any email message or meeting invite selected by user.

(3) It is possible to launch/run an addin automatically as soon as you open a "new Compose Message" (and some more events). You can read about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch

(4) It is also possible to provide "PIN" functionality in addin Taskpane so that it can be pinned in compose/read modes. With this, Addins will always automatically open when any email message or meeting invite is opened.

(5) If you still think your user scenario needs attention, please feel free to share your use-case and filed a new feature request here: https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions